angular injectable chain stop working when moved into a library
In the following angular app named "app-standalone" I chained the injectables CoreService, OuterService, OutmostService and used them in the AppComponent (https://github.com/moky80/angular-injectable-chain/blob/master/app-standalone/src/app/app.component.ts) and they worked as expected:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class CoreService {
  constructor() { console.log("Initialized Core");
} }
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class OuterService {
  constructor(private core: CoreService) {
    console.log("Initialized Outer");
}}
@Injectable({   providedIn: 'root' })
export class OutmostService { constructor(private outer: OuterService) {
    console.log("Initialized Outmost");
}}
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterOutlet],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.scss'
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app-standalone';
  constructor(private outmost: OutmostService){
    console.log("Initialized AppComponent");
  }
}

In the next step, I moved CoreService, OuterService into the angular library named “lib-core” (https://github.com/moky80/angular-injectable-chain/blob/master/lib-core/projects/lib-core/src/lib/lib-core.service.ts):
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CoreService {
  constructor() {
    console.log("Initialized Core");
  }
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class OuterService {
  constructor(private core: CoreService) {
    console.log("Initialized Outer");
  }
}

and created a new app named “app-uses-lib-core” (https://github.com/moky80/angular-injectable-chain/blob/master/app-uses-lib-core/src/app/app.component.ts) which uses the lib-core:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { OuterService } from 'lib-core';

@Injectable({   providedIn: 'root' })
export class OutmostService { constructor(private outer: OuterService) {
    console.log("Initialized Outmost");
}}
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterOutlet],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.scss'
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app-uses-lib-core';
  constructor(private outmost: OutmostService){
    console.log("Initialized AppComponent");
  }
}

“app-uses-lib-core” got the run-time error “NG0203: inject() must be called from an injection context such as a constructor, a factory function, a field initializer, or a function used with runInInjectionContext.”
I couldn’t see why moving the CoreService and OuterService into lib-core could cause an issue. Does somebody have an idea what is wrong with “lib-core” and “app-uses-lib-core” and how can I fix it provided that angular 17 is used?

With @Naren Murali's hint and the link he/she posted https://altimetrikpoland.medium.com/how-to-develop-angular-libraries-locally-395e60a7247f

I could fix the issue by setting projects.projectName.architect.build.options.preserveSymlinks with true in angular.json
It was also mentioned here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/56570#issuecomment-2186195970

The problem lines with how you are doing development, you need to use symlinks to link the library and the application.
When I tried normal method of configuring the package using a local file no issues at all.
"lib-core": "file:../lib-core/dist/lib-core/lib-core-0.0.0-watch+1726241313493.tgz",


You can refer the below articles on how to use a library and application locally to do development.
How to Develop Angular Libraries Locally?
Create an Angular 14 Library, use it locally when developing and publish the package to npm

Have made some small corrections to your library do check it out.
Github Repo

Thanks @Naren Murali your solution works. I still don't understand why installing "../lib-core/dist/lib-core" does not work but "../lib-core/dist/lib-core/lib-core-0.0.1.tgz" works. I thought "../lib-core/dist/lib-core" is for development and "../lib-core/dist/lib-core/lib-core-0.0.1.tgz" is for production but both should work.

@Mako Could be due to mixup of angular libraries, but I think the main reason is, due to the service being evaluated as a class and not as an angular service, by the main angular application. So for some reason, this methods confuses angular and it cannot differentiate between an angular service(@Injectable() decorator) and a javascript class
